# Read value of the element based upon another element XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to read the value of tag 'name' in tag 'id' of value 24. So I would like to get the value of "Obuwie damskie".

```
<Data>
        <Category>                
            <Category>
                <id>15</id>
                <lft>24</lft>
                <rght>0</rght>
                <parent>24</parent>
                <name>Koturny</name>
                <ger_name>Keilabsatzschuhe</ger_name>
                <eng_name/>
                <slug>koturny</slug>
                <eng_slug>-11</eng_slug>
                <ger_slug>keilabsatzschuhe</ger_slug>
                <ProductsCategory>
                    <id>33969</id>
                    <category_id>15</category_id>
                    <product_id>15676</product_id>
                </ProductsCategory>
            </Category>
            <Category>
                <id>24</id>
                <lft>0</lft>
                <rght>0</rght>
                <parent>0</parent>
                <name>Obuwie damskie</name>
                <ger_name>Damenschuhe</ger_name>
                <eng_name/>
                <slug>obuwie-damskie</slug>
                <eng_slug>-21</eng_slug>
                <ger_slug>damenschuhe</ger_slug>
                <ProductsCategory>
                    <id>33970</id>
                    <category_id>24</category_id>
                    <product_id>15676</product_id>
                </ProductsCategory>
            </Category>
        </Category>
    </Data>
```

I would ask you for help, because I'm already sitting all day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate XPath expression wrapped in an `xsl:value` statement is:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/Data/Category/Category[id='24']/name" />
```